# Как прописать growable в dart

Tags: dart

Как вот сюда прописать List.generate(3, (int index) => index * index) growable????

Comment: Нашел свойство growable только не знаю как это туда вписать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/List/List.generate.html

```
List.generate(3, (int index) => index * index, growable: true);
```